# Fetching data from mysql database and display them with primary key value(id)

Tags: php, mysql, session

In search.php

```
<?php
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>

<tr class="td_text">
<td>
<input name="bus_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>" style="border:0px; width:15px; text-align:left;" /></td>
<td> 
<input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>"/>
  </td>
```

book.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}
    $bus_id=$_REQUEST['bus_id'];
$_SESSION['bus_id']=$bus_id;
?>

<div>
<?php
  $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where bus_id='$_SESSION[bus_id]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{ ?> 
<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

This code runs fine when i search & only one bus name displayed and i can show it on the book.php div.. But when there are multiple bus names are displayed after searching, only the last bus name is being displayed on the div of the book.php page, i cant show my bus name according to the bus_id.. 
I think the bus_id variable cant be called properly in my book.php page, any problem with session may So i took `$bus_id` in the select statement instead of session to check, but same problem occured.
Any help ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using mysqli_* functions or PDO insetad of mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: Did u find ne error in session declaration ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code,

In search.php

```
<?php
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    ?>
    <tr class="td_text">
    <td>
    <input name="bus_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>" style="border:0px; width:15px; text-align:left;" /></td>
    <td> 
    <input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>"/>
      </td>

       <td><a href="book.php?bus_id=<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?></a></td>

      </tr>
 <?php }?>
```

In book.php

```
 <?php

    require_once('config.php');
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['bus_id'])){

        header('location:search.php');
    }
     $bus_id=$_REQUEST['bus_id'];       
    ?>      
    <div>
    <?php //display busid realted bus name
       $s= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where bus_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($bus_id)."'");
       $count =mysql_num_rows($s);

       if($count>0){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
            { 
                echo $row['bus_name'];
             }  
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Bus ID";
        }        
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: <td><a href="book.php?id=<?php echo $row['bus_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?></a></td> 

is this line needed ???

Comment: same problem .. only the last bus of the search list is showing :(

Comment: In search.php what needs  to be displayed over there ? So that I can help

Comment: look in search.php page, when i just search for buses, the code is running fine , i want to fetch and show the bus name in my other page  i.e. book.php according to its's primary key bus_id but when there is only one bus in the search result this code runs fine but when there are 2 or more bus names are being searched, i want to see one of the bus name in the book.php page according to it's id, but here only the last bus name of the search list is showing no matter what id i m giving.. so i think the bus_name is not being properly fetched by it's bus_id

Comment: yeah i used ur's.. no result .. but yeah i want to show my bus name in the book.php page ..

Comment: Can you run you select query in phpmyadmin query window and check what are all thh values returned ?` echo "SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]' "`

Comment: the select query is running fine, n its giving me proper results

Comment: yeah i already did that, n if i ve 3 bus names in my search list, it's showing me all the three names but when i change my query to bus_id, it's giving me only the last name of the search list

Comment: bus_id is primary id, it has only one and it is unique id as well, if you change in query with bus_id, it returns only one row which is associated with that row id

Comment: it's a bus website.. i ve inserted 14 records manually by giving it's source point and destination point with other values.. and every record has it's unique bus_id(primary key) .. i m totaly new 2 dis site so m a bit clumsy /.. okk can i ve ur gmail id ?? i reeally need to sort out this problm

Comment: Logic for your code, in search.php file you search and list your bus list based on the keywords, from the serached list, if you want to view the bus name then you clicked the book.php from the secrh.php, it show only one record

Comment: yeah exactly , m saying that .. but here in my code no matter what ID m giving, it's only showing me the last result of the search list

Comment: yeah rite.. but its only giving me the last record... i ve tried session, select statement.. same result

Comment: I get your point, do one thing, post search.php file and book.php file full code along with ur database structure with data, so that i can check my instance and update you

Comment: m mailing u ... z dat okk ??

Comment: Ok, thats ok. I will check

Comment: how is the book.php called from search.php

Comment: book.php page is the action page for search.php page @Bhadra

Comment: when u are looping in while u are creating this elemtn <input name="bus_id" more than once, so when posted it ll take only the last imput s value with name="bus_id".THts why u are always getting last id

Comment: @Bhadra  did you find my code, we have passing bus_id from anchor tag, did you checked that

Comment: in original code shes passing through form i think.inputs were used to post and in the recieving end also through $_REQUEST['bus_id']

Comment: so what should i do now to over come this problem ??? Any code to rectify this problm @Bhadra

Comment: you should nt be posting all the values at once.actually u should not use forms for this.remove form and put link like Chinnu R suggested,but add source and destination in url so that u can take it in book.php

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU soo  much guys... @Bhadra , as per ur suggestion i removed my form action & now chinnu R , ur code z working propely .. m so grtful.. thank u

Comment: @ChinnuR  ur code z working propely .. m so grtful.. thank u .. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU